# How to back to the initial minimal installation of libraries

Tags: python, java, c++, libraries

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.3, with additional backports PPA to get LTS.

From time to time, we can make some big mess with the installation of some libraries we don't really need.

I'm talking about libraries related with C++, Java, Python, etc.

So... I wonder if there is a way to automatically back to the initial minimal installation of all those libraries.

When I talk about "initial", I'm talking about the first moment the Operating System was installed and used.

Is there some command to get this? Where?

Comment: Ubuntu does not have a "System Restore" feature installed by default, since there is no proof-of-purchase or other hogwash to preserve. A complete Ubuntu reinstall-from-scratch is faster than a comparable Windows Restore. You can *make* your own Restore-Point equivalents through judicious use of backups, snapshots, containers, and/or VMs -- your choice. If you are regularly trashing your system through ignorance, use VMs. If you fully understand the problem that causes the system to break, then use LXD containers or snaps.

Comment: @user535733 that comment is more of an answer. Consider converting that comment to a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

For a *dangerous* super clean [downgrade and then upgrade](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-downgrade-ubuntu-linux-system-to-its-previous-version) the system. It's probably more than you want and might require some fixing, but it will be like a new installation.

More likely what you want is a simple [removal or purge](https://www.fosslinux.com/3534/how-to-completely-uninstall-applications-by-command-line-in-ubuntu.htm).

To keep your settings, for subsequent reinstallation:

```
sudo apt-get remove package_name
```

To remove the package, when you won't be reinstalling or want to start from scratch:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove package_name
```

After doing the above, for each package to be removed, do the final cleanup:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: I tried your idea but... The system tells me: "There is not a 'java' package installed". Almost the same with Python and C++. When I use "dpkg", I get  a lot of files related with Java, C++ and Python, and I don't know what are really useful and full needed. So...

Comment: The autoremove should clean up everything. This assumes that you've been using apt (or aptitude) to install, if you've been manually 'make install'ing (or other people have) then you need to manually uninstall (delete the directory) and then use the system tools to install the deliverables (pre-built packages) properly.

Comment: I see! Thanks, Rob! I think it is better to wait for the next great upgrade of Ubuntu (2020-04) and, then, to perform a full clean new installation from the scratch.